# cannot connect asp.net webpage to sql server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a sql database and i'm using sql data connection in my asp.net web application but i'm getting the following ***stack trace error***:

> [InvalidOperationException: The 'SQLNCLI11' provider is not registered
>   on the local machine.]

this is then causing lots of databinding errors

how do i register the data provider?

Comment: search this in google `InvalidOperationException: The 'SQLNCLI11' provider is not registered on the local machine.`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482095/the-sqlncli-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine

Comment: what is your connection string??

Answer (score 0):

You need to install SQL Native client on your computer.

http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/7/c/27c60d49-6dbe-423e-9a9e-1c873f269484/sqlncli_x64.msi

for 32 bits

http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/7/c/27c60d49-6dbe-423e-9a9e-1c873f269484/sqlncli.msi

Answer (score 0):

Resolved issue

Visual studio 2013 and 2012 .net cannot connect to SQL server 2008 by default

Once you have created your data source and done what you need to do with it and tested it locally you need to open the webconfig file, find your data source connection and change 'SQLNCLI11' to SQLNCCLI10 this will prevent you from having to add additional files to your web server.

Caution, you many not be able to edit your data source in visual studio 2012 or 13 unless you change the webconfig data source back to SQLNCLI11