# An OLE DB Provider was not specified in the ConnectionString. 'Provider=SQLOLEDB;

Tags: c#, asp.net, oledbconnection, oledbdatareader, executereader

i trying to run query using C#, i am getting the following problem

> An OLE DB Provider was not specified in the ConnectionString.  An example would be, 'Provider=SQLOLEDB;

my code

```
string strConString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WorkflowConnStr"].ConnectionString.ToString(); 
string sqlstr = "select * from table"        
OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection(strConString);
try
     {myConnection.Open();}
catch (Exception err) 
     { System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(err.Message); }

OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(sqlstr, myConnection);
OleDbDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
```

web.config

```
<add name="WorkflowConnStr" connectionString="Data Source=Server;Initial Catalog=DBName;user id=usr;password=password" providerName="System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection"/>
```

any suggestion ?

Comment: Create a `Test.UDL` and get a valid connection string from that file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try adding this to your connection string,

```
Provider=SQLNCLI10.1
```

So it would be;

```
<add name="WorkflowConnStr" connectionString="Data Source=Server;Initial Catalog=DBName;user id=usr;password=password;Provider=SQLNCLI10.1" providerName="System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection"/>
```

Comment: SQLNCLI10.1 is for SqlServer2008 and SQLNCLI11 for SqlServer2012 according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1499065/521554) link.

Answer (score 1):

Use `SqlConnection` instead of `OleDbConnection`.