# VB SQL ASP Oledb Connection Error

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I got an error 
An OLE DB Provider was not specified in the Connection String.
I tried these Connection String also

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB;
```

Comment: You're using the native client? The provider name is SQLNCLI + version number, e.g. SQLNCLI10 or SQLNCLI11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/ and find correct string for your database.

If you use SQL Server Native Client 10.0 OLE DB Provider, add "Provider=SQLNCLI10.1"

Example,

```
<add name="WorkflowConnStr" 
connectionString="Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;Data Source=Server;Initial Catalog=DBName;user id=usr;password=password"
providerName="System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection"/>
```

[An OLE DB Provider was not specified in the ConnectionString. 'Provider=SQLOLEDB;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23192938/an-ole-db-provider-was-not-specified-in-the-connectionstring-provider-sqloledb)